# open png/pdf in new tab rather than open download window

Tags: asp.net, html, http, iis

I ve to servers with my project. I would like to understand why there is a difference in the behaviour on these 2. On the first one whne i click on:

```
<a href="/multimedia/test.pdf" target="_blank">OPEN</a>
```

the new tab is opened with pdf being rendered and on the other server(the same browser - chrome) new tab is opened but instead of starting rendering pdf download window appears.

Thanks for any sugestions and explanation

the server is IIS 6.0

Answer (score 0):

Seems like one of the browsers has a plugin available, or configured by mefor opening the document itself, while the other one doesn't (this might also mean that the MIME type of the file isn't properly configured so the browser doesn't know what to use to open the file).

If you want to force all browsers to show the download dialog (`attachment`) or trying to open it (`inline`), you can do so with the [Content-Disposition](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.5.1) header field. For instance:

`Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="fileTitle.pdf"` 
or 
`Content-Disposition: inline;`

Answer (score 0):

The one that is downloading the content does not have MIME types are not configured properly.
It is treating the files are unrecognized static files. 
Since the  Content-Disposition header is not set it properly, the browser doesn't know it can render those types.

[Steps to configure MIME types](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/cd72c0dc-c5b8-42e4-96c2-b3c656f99ead.mspx?mfr=true)

Answer (score 0):

The two servers probably send the PDF file with different MIME types in the header, because they are configured differently. If you want PDFs to be opened in the browser, the correct MIME type is `application/pdf`, as defined in [RFC 3778](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3778.txt).

Here is a step-by-step tutorial on how to configure MIME types in IIS 6.0:

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/cd72c0dc-c5b8-42e4-96c2-b3c656f99ead.mspx?mfr=true